# Importing Configurable products With color and size

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, importexport

Importing Configurable product with color and size but only size are visible on site.

What i followed here:

1. I exported all sample data of site.
2. Copy one configurable product with its associated products.
3. Changed All sku(to make this product unique)
4. Deleted: Url keys, images.
5. Checked with Sample-data as well.

This work well but only Size are displaying not Color.

> Whats working: If import product with one configurable option like
>   Color or size then it works even with color-swatches.

Please help me to fix what I am missing.

**Update**: Same issue was here in magento version 1.7 and it was fixed: [Magento Configurable Product Export, Multiple Super Attribute Error Fix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15134/29175). I hope its not issue in magento 2.1.2

Comment: I am still looking for solution

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152651/m2-1-3-importing-a-configurable-product-doesnt-work-but-adding-via-admin-are

Answer (score 0):

You have to Follow below step for creating Configurable product.

1. Create Simple Product with require attribute.
2. Create Configurable Product with `configurable_variations`
    with contain SKU and attributes like `sku=sku_of_simple_product,color=RED,size=XXS`of Simple Product and one another column like `configurable_variation_labels`
    which contain `color=Color,size=Size`.
3. After perform this step you can import configurable product.

It may help you.

Comment: This does not work. I already tried this method before posting here